# Canvas paints the text incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I wrote code which paints the text with canvas. It looks like as shown below:

```
        var canvas = $('<canvas>').css("width", width).css("height", me.scaleHeight);
        var context = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
        context.font = "30px sans-serif";

        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            context.fillText(x*showValue, x*ppt*showValue, 20);
        }
```

canvas paints with this properties:

```
  fillStyle: "#000000"
  filter: "none"
  font:"30px sans-serif"
  globalAlpha:1
  globalCompositeOperation:"source-over"
  imageSmoothingEnabled:true
  imageSmoothingQuality:"low"
  lineCap:"butt"
  lineDashOffset:0
  lineJoin:"miter"
  lineWidth:1
  miterLimit:10
  shadowBlur:0
  shadowColor:"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
  shadowOffsetX:0
  shadowOffsetY:0
  strokeStyle:"#000000"
  textAlign:"center"
  textBaseline:"top"
  webkitImageSmoothingEnabled:true
```

[image: Resulted image]

What property I have set is wrong?

Comment: What does the `<canvas>` element itself look like? Specifically, what are its `height` and `width` attributes?

Comment: Note that when creating a canvas, setting the `width` and `height` property is different from setting the `width` and `height` styles with `css()`

Comment: To be direct and explicit: make sure that the `height` and `width` attributes on the `<canvas>` tag have the same ratio (`height/width`) as the CSS-driven height and width.

Comment: Thank you! I have solved it `div.html('<canvas id="scaleCanvas" width="'+width+'" height="'+me.scaleHeight+'"></canvas>');

      var context = div.find("#scaleCanvas")[0].getContext("2d");`